LaTeX Error when arxiv processing my article
I have a paper to be uploaded on Arxiv, but the following error occurs while processing the files:
LaTeX Error: Unicode character \xe2\x80\x89 (U+2009)
not set up for use with LaTeX.

I tried these packages but it did not work:
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

I would appreciate if anyone could help me on this issue.
Thank you very much

Without minimal working example I can only guess: U+2009 is a Thin Space aka Narrow No-Break Space. Maybe you have it somewhere in your document file(s) (including the bibliography file). You can try \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{\,} in your preamble to replace it by a valid TeX macro. Or use something strange like INVALID instead of \, to be able to search for “INVALID” in the generated PDF to find the place, where the Thin Space is used.

My wild guess would be that the character snuck in via a copy/paste.  I would compile the file not on Arxiv and change cabohah's suggestion to \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{RETYPE THIS PART} and then look through the pdf for where the character occurs.
